# User Response to Transposed Calendar Representation

Tags: calendar

I am investigating the use of a transposed calendar, in which the rows are the days of the week and the columns are the weeks. Has anyone researched this usage? Does anyone have any examples of this usage in the wild? How did users respond?

Here is my mockup:

[image]

Comment: It's breaking an extremely common convention, so I'd expect problems, however it is an interesting way to present the data if the day of week is the most important factor.

Comment: What is the reason you want to use this inverted interface? It's hard to answer a usability question without some sense of what "usable" is here. Presumably there's some sort of problem you were trying to solve.

Comment: @Jonathan I meant to lead into that question but really didn't. I have to assume attention is being drawn to the days of the week but I'm not sure of that and I would like to know why as well.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to keep adjacent days next to each other but use a horizontal layout. In other words, the last day of a month must always be adjacent to the first day of the next month. This is easy to do with a vertical layout of months, but impossible in a horizontal layout if maintaining the conventional look of a calendar.

Comment: @Stanish Thanks for the additional info. Hope you don't mind if I keep probing - Why is it that the last day of the month needs to be adjacent to the first day of the next month?

Comment: I'd like to use the visualization in order to demonstrate availability information. People tend to look at their schedule in chunks of a week rather than individual days. The division between months is almost arbitrary in the user's mental model. When they check to see whether they are free for a week, having that one week spread across two lines breaks their flow. I realize this is somewhat pedantic.

Comment: @Stanish: I like the idea. That said, most calendars solve that by allowing you to display the days of the previous/next month on the lines of the first and last weeks. Usually they are displayed in a lighter color to indicate that they are in another month. It does mean that weeks spanning two months are shown twice.

Comment: I still don't get why there is extra benefit in being presented in a horizontal format and why you can't apply the same representation in a vertical format like this [example](http://www.thinkui.co.uk/examples/calendar.png) . It's perfectly common to have first day of month next to last day of previous month on hotel, cottage and other accommodation booking sites which need to show weekly availability...

Comment: If it is for work-week planning, put Monday at the top. If it is for week*end* events, put Saturday and Sunday at the bottom. If neither, then follow the ISO standard.

Answer (score 1):

I can only recall seeing this layout once before. Here's an example in the wild: http://annystudio.com/calendars/ which has free printable calendars in both weeks-in-rows and weeks-in-columns format.

Perhaps [contact Anny](http://annystudio.com/info/contacts/) to see if she could share relative popularity/customer comments on the week-in-a-row format (admittedly, it's designed for print, so any learnings may not translate to interactive).